# Story about a lady who dreams about turning into a witch

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The story was in a small anthology volume whose cover showed a haunted house done in green and purple lights, I think, with the title "Horror" or something like that. I read it in the mid-90s.

The story was about a lady who dreamed that she turned into a green witch with warts, and the dream also had a voice that I don't remember. As the story goes on, everyone else heard the voice, and I think it helped turn everyone into their worst nightmares, and it ends with the lady as the green witch with warts.